# Can the landlord of an AST restrict the tenant from having house guests or even house sitters?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, tenant, assured-shorthold-tenancy

I suppose that the distinction between a guest and a house sitter might be that one remains while the tenant is gone while the other would stay to visit the tenant themselves.

But as an AST constitutes a tenant's home, how much latitude does a LL have to say what he or she does with it, who she has over, for how long, and whether she accompanies them the entire time for which they stay, without infringing upon the tenants' implied covenants of exclusive possession and/or quiet enjoyment?

Comment: I'm beginning to think you need a new landlord. =P

Comment: Lol... Only just beginning?